# List view link on sectionHeader

Tags: visualforce, list-view

[image]

I want to show List view as a link on vf like it is shown in image.

Comment: You need to override standard List View button

Answer (score 0):

try adding this code in your Apex PageBlockSection

```
<apex:facet name="header">
        <apex:outputpanel >
            <apex:outputText style="font-weight:bold;font-size:13px;float:left;" value="Your Text"/>
                <apex:commandLink style="float:right;" value="List View"  action="{!actionOnLink}"/>
        </apex:outputpanel>
</apex:facet>
```

Comment: what will be the action for list view?

Comment: It depends on what you want from commanLink

Comment: yes. But we really cant put listview as like that. I am struggling for listview api to pass as a link.

Comment: share your code so that we can get idea what you are doing